# How to pause and resume download in News Stand?

Tags: ios5

Can we pause and resume download in news stand as we do it in nsurlconnection setting range for NSMutablerequest ??

I tried to set the range for the NSMutablerequest for the NKAssetDownload.
But it will start downloading from the beginning....

```
NSMutableURLRequest *urlReq=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:downloadURl]];
int totalLength=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"TotalLength"] intValue];
int recievedLength=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Recieved"] intValue];
[urlReq setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bytes=%d-%d",recievedLength,totalLength] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Range"];
NKAssetDownload *mAssetDownload = [mIssue addAssetWithRequest:urlReq];
```

But download begins from first and not from the range.

Comment: Ideally Apple's newsstand framework should do it by itself(resuming unfinished downloads, when to pause, when to start again etc)But I am having hard time making the downloads smooth in my app. I am downloading from Amazon S3 and each time my app go to background or iPad auto-locks, the downloads stops and when I open app soon my download stops with "didFailWithError" called. Most of the time it is "RequestTimtTooSkewed" error and sometime it is timeout. And the only option is to download the file from zero. I dont know why Newsstand queue is not retaining the broken downloads to resume them.

Comment: Are you resuming all the queued downloads when the app comes back in the applicationDidBecomeActive: or didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:?